# Mutate with across and .names, how can I list the columns

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr, across

I am trying to name the output of an across function using `{fn}` and a number for the column.
I have this idea for the command, but don't work:

```
iris %>% 
  mutate(
    across(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width, list(var = ~ . -1),
           .names = "{fn}{1:4}")
  )
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
x Variables must be length 1 or 5
ℹ Input `..1` is `across(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width, list(var = ~. - 1), .names = "{fn}{1:5}")`
```

I expect for output that I would get 4 new columns with names such as `var1`, `var2`, `var3` and `var4`.

Comment: Your code runs without error for me.  The error message makes me think that you might have manipulated the iris dataframe and introduced an extra variable between `Sepal.Length` and `Petal.Width`.  Have you tried replacing `{1:4}` with `{1:5}`?

Comment: You're right! I tried different things with no luck. The last command was only an idea about what I wanted... and that works! 
Thanks!